# 400 bad request Nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) in GCP

Tags: nginx, google-compute-engine

getting an error in host: 443 & while connecting on host showing 400bad request error.

```
(venv)root@*****-dev:/usr/local/src/security_monkey/nginx# # sudo nginx
Enter PEM pass phrase:*****
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

Comment: @ viswanath before you create any additional Question posts on one of the Stack Exchange sites you may want to review the 'How do I ask a good question' Guide https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask and the 'quality standards' post in META https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you have something already running on your HTTPS port.  I'm not familiar with Google Cloud Platform and your question lacks a tremendous amount of detail but; you can try to run either of the following commands to determine if something is already running on port 443

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 443
```

or

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 443
```

Comment: sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 443
nginx     22838             root    8u  IPv4 1031022      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     22839         www-data    8u  IPv4 1031022      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     22840         www-data    8u  IPv4 1031022      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     22842         www-data    8u  IPv4 1031022      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     22843         www-data    8u  IPv4 1031022      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)

Comment: Nginx Listening bur Web UI showing error.

Comment: Can you post your nginx config file and possibly the output from your access.log or error.log?